# What is best practice to store a list of an object within another object

Tags: c#, list, object

I have an object called `product` and an object called `products`.

```
class product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class products
{
    public List<product> product { get; set; }
}
```

In the objects `products` property `product` i want to store multiple products. This i how i did it in a small prototype solution:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        products productlist = new products();
        List<product> listofproduct = new List<product>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            product p = new product();
            p.Id = i;
            p.Name = "product with id = " + i.ToString();

            listofproduct.Add(p);
        }

        productlist.product = listofproduct;

        foreach (product prod in productlist.product)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prod.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to solve this? Or do you do it in another way in object oriented programming?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your code this way:

```
productlist.product = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                                .Select
                                (
                                     id => new product 
                                     { 
                                         id = id, 
                                         name = $"product with id = {id}" 
                                     }
                                ).ToList();
```

Well, actually you could express the same code in many ways, but the `for` loop that you've already implemented in your code is fine.

If you want some advise, you should follow .NET coding conventions:

- Classes with pascal-casing: `Product`.
- Variables with camel-case: `productList`. `listOfProduct`...
- A collection of products should be a plural identifier, and properties are pascal-cased: `Products`.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public Product(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id=id;
        this.Name=name;
    }
    public void WriteInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", Id); 
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", Name);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var productList=new LinkedList<Product>;
    productList.AddLast(new Product(1,Apple));
    productList.AddLast(new Product(2,Banana));
    
    foreach(var product in productList)
    {
        product.WriteInfo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use a `struct` for this. No, I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `LINQ` and keep your current structure, you *could* eliminate the need to create full instances in your loop, and the need for `listofproduct`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    productlist.product.Add(new product {
        p.Id = i;
        p.Name = "product with id = " + i.ToString();
    });
}
```

However, the best practice for writing code should be:

> What is the easiest way for me to maintain and understand this code?

So if the way you wrote the code in your question is what makes you feel comfortable, then by all means do it. However, I ***strongly*** recommend you follow the conventions laid out by MSDN for [Capitalization Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx).